# Augmented reality not showing marker when device in landscape mode

Tags: android

I am using https://github.com/raweng/augmented-reality-view for my augmented reality project. It's working fine when device is in portrait mode, but when I rotate device then at that time marker are not visible on screen. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: can you please post what other things you tried to use that library  ?

Comment: i does nothing,I use same code and change ui according to my requirement and added portrait functionality.

Comment: do it properly it will work.